# Recover files from HDD with partition type unrecognized and boot sector that can't be read

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, testdisk

I was trying to retrieve data from an old (9 year old) HDD, which was working fine a month ago, after leaving powered off for a month. When I turned on my Windows PC on, it took a long while to boot [5-10mn] and display files in Explorer; since it took so long to display the files and Performance tab of Task Manager showing disk usage always at 100%, I ran `chkdsk`, which took a few hours and didn't improve anything.

I started transferring files to my other disk [SSD: `C:`] anyway and noticed the HDD [`D:`] was spinning up and stopping repeatedly, with the transfer speeds going from 0 MB/s to ~60 MB/s. I thought it could be a power issue, so when it stopped at 0 MB/s for a long time, I turned off the PC and plugged the HDD into my more recent PC, where it took 5min to boot, with Explorer freezing

- HDD appeared in the list of drives, but wouldn't open and displayed no information about size, so I plugged it back to the older PC, but now Explorer couldn't display a single file at all: [image]

What can I do to recover my files?

---

**What I've tried:**

- Running `chkdsk`
- **Checked S.M.A.R.T data with CrystalDiskInfo and the disk has 23 bad sectors:** [image: [image]] [image: [image]]
- **Resolving with Linux tools, where Disks utility showed NTFS partition type as Unknown:** [image: [image]]
- **Running `testdisk` to analyse and try to recover the partition structure:**

  1. Selected `/dev/sdc` → `Intel/PC partition` → `Analyse`
  2. Current partition structure: [image: [image]]
  3. Quick search resulted with: [image: [image1]] [image: [image2]]

  - Log:

    ```
    Sun Mar 27 10:16:11 2022
    TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019

    /dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
    /dev/sda: size       976773168 sectors
    /dev/sda: user_max   976773168 sectors
    /dev/sda: native_max 976773168 sectors
    /dev/sdb: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
    /dev/sdb: size       234441648 sectors
    /dev/sdb: user_max   234441648 sectors
    /dev/sdb: native_max 234441648 sectors
    /dev/sdc: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
    /dev/sdc: size       1953525168 sectors
    /dev/sdc: user_max   1953525168 sectors
    /dev/sdc: native_max 1953525168 sectors
    /dev/sdc: dco        1953525168 sectors

    Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
    Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/loop4 - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
    Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/loop5 - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
    Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/loop6 - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512
    Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/loop7 - 0 B - 0 sectors, sector size=512

    Hard disk list
      Disk /dev/sda - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63, sector size=512 - Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB, S/N:S3Z2NB0KB56029K, FW:RVT02B6Q
      Disk /dev/sdb - 120 GB / 111 GiB - CHS 14593 255 63, sector size=512 - Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB, S/N:S1D5NSAF910822R, FW:EXT0BB6Q
      Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63, sector size=512 - WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0, S/N:WD-WCATRC617853, FW:05.01D05
      Disk /dev/sdd - 8178 MB / 7800 MiB - CHS 1022 252 62, sector size=512 - SMI USB DISK, FW:1100
      Disk /dev/loop0 - 72 MB / 69 MiB - 141848 sectors (RO), sector size=512
      Disk /dev/loop1 - 968 MB / 923 MiB - 1891320 sectors (RO), sector size=512
      Disk /dev/loop2 - 1761 MB / 1679 MiB - 3440248 sectors (RO), sector size=512
      Disk /dev/loop3 - 674 MB / 642 MiB - 1316496 sectors (RO), sector size=512

    Partition table type (auto): Intel
      Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0
      Partition table type: Intel

    Analyse Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
      Geometry from i386 MBR: head=255 sector=63
      NTFS at 12/223/20

    Current partition structure:
      1 P HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20 121601  25 24 1953314816
      No partition is bootable

    search_part()
      Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
      NTFS at 0/32/33
      filesystem size           204800
      sectors_per_cluster       8
      mft_lcn                   8533
      mftmirr_lcn               2
      clusters_per_mft_record   -10
      clusters_per_index_record 1
        HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800
        NTFS, blocksize=4096, 104 MB / 100 MiB

      file_pread(6,16,buffer,206848(12/223/20)) read err: Partial read
      file_pread(6,16,buffer,6731235(419/0/1)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,1,buffer,6731235(419/0/1)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,16,buffer,6811774(424/3/26)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,1,buffer,6811774(424/3/26)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,16,buffer,325942848(20289/1/1)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,1,buffer,325942848(20289/1/1)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,16,buffer,325942849(20289/1/2)) read err: Input/output error
      file_pread(6,1,buffer,325942849(20289/1/2)) read err: Input/output error

      recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/500, s_mnt_count=1/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
      recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
      recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 16384000
      recover_EXT2: part_size 131072000

      Last mount time:    Tue Sep 11 09:35:30 2018
        Linux                26272 233 10 34431 196  5  131072000
        ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 67 GB / 62 GiB

      recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/16, s_mnt_count=0/10, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
      recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
      recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 524288
      recover_EXT2: part_size 4194304
        Linux                89894  66 29 90155  87 44    4194304 [system]
        ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 2147 MB / 2048 MiB

      BAD_RS LBA=3757975400 3337278
      check_FAT: can't read FAT boot sector
      check_part_i386 failed for partition type 01
        FAT12                233923  38 12 335156  37 40 1626308111

      This partition ends after the disk limits. (start=3757975400, size=1626308111, end=5384283510, disk end=1953525168)
      BAD_RS LBA=2005443740 4058207
      check_FAT: can't read FAT boot sector
      check_part_i386 failed for partition type 01
        FAT12                124833  25 21 138927 166 20  226428993

      This partition ends after the disk limits. (start=2005443740, size=226428993, end=2231872732, disk end=1953525168)

    Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
      Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...
      The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 2756 GB / 2567 GiB)
      The following partitions can't be recovered:
        FAT12                124833  25 21 138927 166 20  226428993
        FAT12                233923  38 12 335156  37 40 1626308111

      Results
        * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800
          NTFS, blocksize=4096, 104 MB / 100 MiB

        P Linux                26272 233 10 34431 196  5  131072000
          ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 67 GB / 62 GiB

        P Linux                89894  66 29 90155  87 44    4194304 [system]
          ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 2147 MB / 2048 MiB

    Hint for advanced users: dmsetup may be used if you prefer to avoid rewriting the partition table for the moment:
      echo "0 204800 linear /dev/sdc 2048" | dmsetup create test0
      echo "0 131072000 linear /dev/sdc 422074368" | dmsetup create test1
      echo "0 4194304 linear /dev/sdc 1444151296" | dmsetup create test2
    ```

Comment: I wish we could warn enough people in advance that if you suspect a drive is failing, the **worst possible** thing to do is to run chkdsk. Its job is to make the filesystem coherent, not to save your files. It will sacrifice any & all data to achieve that goal.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your answer. I will take this advice next time! Now I suspect my data is still here (at least we don't know yet), my issue is about being able to access the content again, and for that I guess I need to fix the partition structure.

Comment: No. Read the linked duplicate. The more you play with the drive, the lower your chances get. You have already made the task 10 times harder by running chkdsk. Disconnect the drive until you are ready with 2 spares. One to duplicate the original to & one to do the recovery to. This is the price of not having a backup. If you want to ever see your data again, do this properly.

Comment: @Torayl Please do not screenshot terminal output; instead, please copy/paste it into a code box _(see formatting bar)_